# MySQL query time out while querying JSON object

Tags: mysql, json, query-optimization

The following query seems to generate an infinite loop, since it times out after 30 seconds. Running it in C++ never returns to the code.

```
SELECT author_obj->>'$.name' FROM author WHERE author_obj->'$.name' NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT author_obj->'$.name' 
    FROM response INNER JOIN author ON response.author_id = author.id 
    WHERE response.parent IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY author.id);
```

The inner part runs as expected and returns authors in the database that have answered to some other post in 1.5 seconds.

The goal of the query is to find all users that only post messages, but never answer to other users, where the users are saved as JSON objects.

Comment: A query can take a long time, but it can't do an infinite loop. This query is probably executing the 1.5 second subquery once for each row in the `author` table, so it could take hours or days to finish.

Comment: If you want more help, edit your question and include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table, and also run `EXPLAIN` for this query and include the optimization report. This is standard basic information for any query optimization question. Don't make us guess at your data types, indexes, and constraints. Help us help you!

Comment: Also tell us the MySQL version. Run `SELECT @@version;` and show the result.

Comment: And finally: please paste the requested information as _text_, not as screenshots.

Comment: Mysql is terrible at `WHERE [NOT] IN (SELECT...`. If you refactor as a join it will be much faster.

Comment: Thank you, especially the last comment helped a lot. I replaced it with a left join opperation and it runs in quite fast now.

Comment: That is a rather complex query, I would like to see if the Optimizer improved on it.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT author_obj->>'$.name'
FROM author 
WHERE author_obj->'$.name' NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT author_obj->'$.name' 
    FROM response
    INNER JOIN author ON response.author_id = author.id 
    WHERE response.parent IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY author.id)
```

*might* be faster this way:

```
SELECT a1.author_obj->>'$.name'
FROM author a1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM
    FROM response r
    INNER JOIN author a2 ON r.author_id = a2.id 
    WHERE a2.author_obj->'$.name' = a1.author_obj->'$.name'
      AND r.parent IS NOT NULL)
```

(Caveat: I may not have refactored it correctly.)